# Does allure plugin for python have setup/teardown facilities?

Tags: python, python-unittest, allure

Does allure plugin for python have setup/teardown facilities, like those of python unittest module?

Answer (score 1):

Allure just add addtitional categories like steps for tests and features/stories for group of test. Test fixture is responsibility of testing framework not reporting like Allure.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such facilities like `setUp` or `tearDown` in `allure`.
But you can use the py.test fixtures to implement setUp and tearDown by yourself.